# How can I program a line chart using D3.js to visualise a data which is received from a server side ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, d3.js

I have this link which is on the server side

http://www.tr-l6/STWebService/Service.svc/session/Fetchnodehistorybyname?strnodename=starbucks

to receive a data in json format , this is the data

```
{"Id":466,"Name":"korea",                                                                               
"Occurrences":
[{"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398207600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":27},    
 {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398726000000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":1},   
 {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":4}, 
 {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1399071600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":303}]}
```

This the code I used to draw a line chart BUT this code is programmed to recieve the data from the same pc . It's doesn't retrieve the data from the server side... My question how Can I use **Jquery** and **Ajax** to transform this code to draw a line chart by retrieving the data from the server side using that link which is mentioned above . bare in mind , that my json file is nested one. 
This is the full code :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

  body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  }

   path.line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #666;
   stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  path.area {
  fill: #e7e7e7;
  }

 .axis {
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .x.axis line {
  stroke: #fff;
  }

  .x.axis .minor {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
  }

  .x.axis path {
  display: none;
  }

  .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  }

  </style>
  <body>

 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>

  var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var parseDate1 = d3.time.format.iso.parse;

  // Scales and axes. Note the inverted domain for the y-scale: bigger is up!
  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
  y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
  xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(true),
  yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("right");

   // An area generator, for the light fill.
  var area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.Occurrences.OccurrenceDate); })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Occurrences.OccurrenceFrequency); });

  // A line generator, for the dark stroke.
  var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.OccurrenceDate); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.OccurrenceFrequency); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("data3.json", function(error, data) {
    data.Occurrences.forEach(function(d){
    var dc 
    dc = d.OccurrenceDate.substring(6, 16)
     dc = new Date(dc*1000)
    d.OccurrenceDate= parseDate1(dc)
    d.OccurrenceFrequency = +d.OccurrenceFrequency

return d;
    });
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.OccurrenceDate; })); 
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.OccurrenceFrequency; })]);

   svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);

   svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
   });  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retreive JSON data using d3 as follows;

```
d3.json("/path/to/json", function(d) {
    //rendering code
}
```

and then, inside the callback function (in place of rendering code) you can access the JSON data using the variable "d".

The following summerizes the general procedure to follow after retreiving the data;

```
//Create a svg
svg = d3.select("selector_to_some_DOM_element").append("svg");

//Then append text for each data JSON entry
svg.selectAll(".yourClassNameHere")
        .data(d) //received data
        .enter()
        .text(function (d) { //add some text
            //using OccurrenceFrequency
            return d.OccurrenceFrequency
        });
```

You can read more detailed d3 JSON data management at http://pothibo.com/2013/09/d3-js-how-to-handle-dynamic-json-data/